# Is it possible to change the power of the shots by turrets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

In the [Portal Gun mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/199391-125-portal-gun-reconstructed-v1-thermal-discouragement-beams/) is it possible to change the power of turrets bullets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, It is not possible to change the damage of bullets fired from turrets.

The most you can do to turrets is change their Range of fire and Explosion magnitude. The values for those settings are found in the mod_PortalGun.properties file in your .minecraft/mods folder.

Hope this helps.